# nmcli get actual name of interface (e.g. tun0) from connection name

Tags: network-interface, networkmanager, vpn, route, nmcli

1.) I would like to get the actual name of an interface from the connection name used by nmcli.
In my case, I have several VPN-connections, let's call one of them `my-vpn`.
Now, I do `nmcli con up id my-vpn` and the VPN-connection is started and is assigned an actual interface name, let's say `tun0`.

Specifically, I want to get the `tun0` from a command, using only the `my-vpn` name, either using `nmcli`, `ip`, `ifconfig` or similar default networking tools.

I tried e.g. `nmcli -g connection.interface-name connection show my-vpn`, which only gives me `my-vpn` as an output, where I would have expected to get the interfaces' name `tun0`.

2.) Alternatively, is it possible to (simply) rename a `tun0` device e.g. to `my-vpn`? I would like to add routes to my VPN-connections without having to care about in which order they were started (as they are enumerated as `tun0`, `tun1`, etc.., by the order in which they were initiated).

Comment: Is `nmcli connection show --active` what you are searching for? My englisch in not well, so I hope I understood your right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `nmcli` together with `ip` to obtain the interface name from the connection name by matching on the IPv4 address:

```
ip -br addr show to "$(nmcli -g ip4.address con show <connection-name>)" | cut -d ' ' -f 1
```

Comment: Is there a reason that "nmcli -g connection.interface-name con show <connection-name>" wouldn't work instead for a VPN connection?

Comment: @Perkins a value for `connection.interface-name` may not always be available or may be incorrect, depending on how the VPN connection was created. Using either `ip addr` or `nmcli dev`, we can get an actual interface in use by the VPN connection.

Comment: Hmmm...  Ok.  Of course, that kind of sounds like a Network Manager bug.

Answer (score 0):

NetworkManager has this information, but it seems like it's only available on the device. Hence, first get the device(s) then look it up:

```bash
nmcli -g GENERAL.DEVICES con show <connection-name> | while read dev; do nmcli -g GENERAL.IP-IFACE device show "$dev"; done
```

Comment: Haven't tested that this works for VPN interfaces (but I think it should?) -- I am using this to correct for an LTE interface that has a different NetworkManager device name than it's interface name. I expect it's the same issue and this seems relevant enough and probably helpful.

Comment: I think this can be done with `nmcli -g GENERAL.IP-IFACE con show "your connection"` as well. See also [this bug report](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/NetworkManager/NetworkManager/-/issues/218).